# Array to string conversion fails for `Dir.glob`

Tags: ruby

I need to search for the sub folder in a particular directory using Ruby. For example d:/abc/xyz/*/file.txt . In the place of * i can have anything.
I have tried Dir.glob() but it return array which i could not convert into string.
Is there any other method i can achieve this. 
I have to copy file from another location into this path.
when i have output of Dir.glob() in var and used like this
system("copy C:\abc\xyz #{var}") it doesn't copy.
Can anyone suggest me the best way to do this.

My code is

var = Dir.glob("D://backup//ffi//*//window").first

system("copy D:\backup\automate-scripts #{var}")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you remove all the formatting that made the question readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
temp_dir = //generate path for your dynamic directory_name

file_name = Dir.glob("d:/abc/xyz/#{temp_dir}/file.txt").first
```

`.first` will return first array element in string. If there isn't any file with given name(`file.txt`) `Dir.glob` will return a nil class.

If you want to list all directories use:

```
Dir["**/"].each {|x| puts x}
```

Comment: @Paul: Thanks buddy. That's give me the string format. but when i try to use it inside system("copy d:x\y\z #{file_name}) it says syntax of command is incorrect

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ruby


var = Dir.glob("D://backup//ffi//*//window").first

system("copy D:\\backup\\automate-scripts #{var}")

Comment: Not here in your original question qith proper tags, so that we can understand better.